# Installed Kubuntu on old hard drive and now it's making loud clicking noises

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, kubuntu, hard-drive-failure

I recently installed Kubuntu on a very old hard drive (it's 10 years old at least). It installed OK, but when I started the computer, I heard the hard drive making loud noises – sounds most like the bearings. When I clicked the turn-off option, it began the countdown, but when I clicked 'Turn Off', it said 'Suspend to Ram', and continued the 30 second countdown. When the countdown was over, it turned off.

Is that normal? And is it a good idea to continue using that hard drive? I am not using it for day-to-day use, by the way.

Comment: The hard drive might be failing. Check the SMART data and make backups to be safe, if you don't trust that hard drive. Otherwise, the countdown is normal.

Comment: Check with the hard drive may be it might cause that issue since it is old but the time 30 sec seems to be normal for the turnoff. So hopefully can check with the hdd for noise.

Comment: 10 years is when hard drives fail. Mine failed when it about 8.5 years and Windows became very slow